# How to convert first order singular ODE to integral equation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, power-series

I have the following ODE:
\begin{equation}
v(x)y'=a(x)y^2+b(x)y,~~~y(0)=\varphi,~~v(0)=v(1)=0.
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
I know that for a similar equation of the form $\varepsilon y'=a(x)y^2+b(x)y~~$ (where $\varepsilon$ is a constant which can be zero) we can use the so-called Thikonov theory which consist in seeking a solution in the following form:
\begin{equation}
y=X(x,\varepsilon)+U(z,\varepsilon)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\bigg(X_k(x)+U_k(z)\bigg)\varepsilon^k
\end{equation}
with $z=\frac{x}{\varepsilon},$ $X(x,\varepsilon)$ is the outer solution and $U(z,\varepsilon)$ is the initial layer inner solution and satisfy $U(z,\varepsilon)\rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow \infty.$
My question: Is there any way to convert this equation  into integral equation ? Alternatively, can the Thikonv theory be applied to this kind of equation?

Comment: $(1)$ You can rewrite the ODE as the integral equation $y(x)=y(0)+\int_0^x\frac{1}{v(s)}\left[a(s)y^2(s)+b(s)y(s)\right]ds$. $(2)$ Your ODE has the form of a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation). It can be solved explicitly.

Comment: Thank you @Gonçalo. But for (1) I think the integral blows up at 0, no? Am wrong?

Comment: It depends on the behavior of $v(x), a(x), b(x),$ and $y(x)$ near $x=0$.